# Python Hough Transform implementation issue

Tags: python, hough-transform

There are some implementations of the Hough transform on the internet, only I don't understand a part:
When we find our couple (rho, theta), we have to go back to Cartesian.
To draw the lines here is what is used:

```
  for i in range (len(Liste_p)):
        a = cos(Liste_theta[i])
        b = sin(Liste_theta[i])
        x0 = a*Liste_p[i]
        y0 = b*Liste_p[i]
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))  # x1 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)-1000sin(theta))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))   # y1 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)+1000cos(theta))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))  # x2 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)+1000sin(theta))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))   # y2 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)-1000cos(theta))
        plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],color="r")
```

But what is multiplication by 1000?
In fact I do not understand the link with the line that we are supposed to draw

Comment: What are the magnitudes of the points in the list?

Comment: The points in the lists are the points associated with the pairs (rho, theta) after Hough transformation.
for rho: from 0 to the maximum defined by the diagonal of the image
for theta: angles in radians

Comment: So `Liste_p` is on the order of 1000?

Comment: Not necessary, finally there could be only one element in the list, all implementations of Hough draw their final lines like this. For exemples :
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/line-detection-python-opencv-houghline-method/
- https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/lane-detection-tutorial-in-opencv-python-using-hough-transform/
But no explaination on the 1000 factor